# Multisite on single wordpress

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain, domain-mapping, configuration

I've got single site on instance of wordpress. Now I want to add second blog so second site (separate domain) under the same hosting so the same wordpress instance.

Is it possible to achieve it having sweparate not related domains?
I'm new in wordpress area and most of tutorials I saw are about multidomain with having subdomain or subdirectories so not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can have a single WordPress Multisite installation serve up more than one domain.

1. [Set up Multisite.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) For this site, it won't matter if you use subdirectory or subdomain. (If you plan to add other sites to this Multisite network, choose the option you'd prefer to use for those other sites.)
2. Create your new site.
3. Go to the new site's Dashboard, and mouse over its name in the admin bar at the top of the page. Select **Edit Site** from the dropdown menu.
4. Change the **Site Address (URL)** to what you want it to be, and save the changes.

**Note:** You'll need to make sure that your new domain name is registered, and that its DNS entry points to the appropriate IP address. You'll also need to make sure that your WordPress server's configuration is set to accept requests for the new domain name. This is something you'll either need to handle yourself, or take up with your hosting provider.

Comment: Looks like I did it before I posted, but from some reason it took longer than I supposed. In fact it's working

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not talking about Using two domains with the same wordpress install IE you use the same site with two different names.

If you are using two DIFFERENT wordpress installations, this is super simple. Its all about associating that second domain with your webhost, i suggest you look into using your second domain as an addon domain. Given that you've just got started I imagine you're in a shared hosting solution like godaddy.

Godaddy would have you add an addon domain, or you could use a subdomain and point that to a given folder on your server.

You will ofcourse need a seperate database, and to install wordpress in that folder but you should have no issues.

IF you used something like softalicious or some hosting provided installer you are a in for a little headache as at this point you need to understand how to put files on your server. That would involve ftp etc.

I hope this helps. But really your question isn't a wordpress question its a hosting question one specific to your hosting providers pattern for using multiple domains with their servers.